# Mounting btrfs partition with compression enabled

Tags: btrfs, compression, udisks

I've got a btrfs partition on a SSD drive.
This partition is not mounted by default, it's not root. It's just a plain data partition which is mounted on demand. Nothing fancy.

The btrfs partition was created by `gparted`. It's recognized by the system. I can mount it. I can `btrfs filesystem defragment` it. Basics seem working.

However, I've selected btrfs because I want a compressed partition, which is something btrfs offers (compared to ext4). I'm also aware that it's possible to select different compression levels, and would like to try it.

But, no parameter was ever specified anywhere, neither at partition creation time, nor at mount time.
Looking at documentation around, from what I could read, compression seems to be decided during mount.
So, if I want `zstd` at maximum compression level, I should specify `--compress-force=zstd:19`.

OK, but the way I'm mounting the partition, I just click in the GUI folder manager, and it automounts the partition. And that's the way I want it to mount. I don't want to have to use a command line every time. Once again, no idea which parameters are selected by the GUI, nowhere is it proposed to specify anything, so I presume it's uncompressed, which defeats the point.

I had a look at `disks` utility too, in case it would correspond. There is a "mount options" tab, but once there, it's unclear if any field can be used to issue compression parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It is compressed by default. It check compressibility when you copy something if it seems compressible it will compress it zstd is default. If you force it documentation says you will still gain %20 space efficiency with %5 loss of speed in general conditions ...